# Open javascript popup on image button click

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, popup

I'm trying to open popup window when i click on image button in asp.net website, but when i click on image button the pop up window shows up for like one seconds and then disappears.when i use  tag, it shows the pop up window, but when i try with the other way, it disappears. Am i missing something in the code.

```
 <div id="cover"></div>
 <div id="dialog">
My Dialog Content
<br><input type="text">
<br><input type="button" value="Submit">
<br><a href="#" onclick="closePopUp('dialog');">[Close]</a>
</div>
<a href="#" onclick="showPopUp('dialog');">Show</a>
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton3" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/slika/PLUS.gif" onClientClick="showPopUp('dialog');"  />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clicking on `ImageButton` causes postback - that reloads the page with no popup shown. This link describes a way to have an `ImageButton` that does not cause form submision : [Can I create an ASP.NET ImageButton that doesn't postback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703267/can-i-create-an-asp-net-imagebutton-that-doesnt-postback)

```
onClientClick="showPopUp('dialog');return false;"
```