# Ajax Post URL not working on ASP.net Image Button OnClientClickClick

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

Ajax Post URL not working on  ASP.net Image Button  OnClientClick . I want to get the value through Ajax Post URL in OnClientClick.

```
 <asp:ImageButton ID="btngo" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/oea_images/login_btn.png"
      OnClick="btngo_Click" OnClientClick="clean_all();" Width="80px" />

    function clean_all() {
        try {
            alert("enter");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "WebForm9.aspx/ForceOut",
                data: "{}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msgs) {
                    //alert(msgs);
                    //alert(msgs.d);
                    if (msgs.d == "out") {
                        alert("check");
                    }
                }
            });
        } catch (ex) {
            alert(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: did you checked it in firebug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return false` to avoid postback. Also remove the OnClick attribute of the asp  Image button and give a try.

```
       var varglobal=false;
                function clean_all() {
                        try {
                          if(!varglobal){
                            alert("enter");
                            $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: "WebForm9.aspx/ForceOut",
                                data: "{}",
                                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                dataType: "json",
                                success: function (msgs) {
                                    //alert(msgs);
                                    //alert(msgs.d);
                                    if (msgs.d == "out") {
                                        alert("check");

                                        varglobal=true;
                                        $("#btngo").click();// hopes master page isn't                           used.

                                    }
                                }
                            });
                          }
                        } catch (ex) {
                            alert(ex.Message);
                        }
                     return varglobal;
                    }
```

**Since it's an ASP Image button, the** `return false` **maynot prevent the post back**(The postback is not a default function of `input[type=image]`). Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703267/can-i-create-an-asp-net-imagebutton-that-doesnt-postback) to know it how.

When a postback happens, the Ajax request to server will get cancelled and error function will be executed. You can avoid this by preventing the postback.

Comment: Its working fine and also i want use  OnClick attribute with the same image button. Is its possible

Answer (score 0):

If you use this way, you can avoid postback, but you can't call the server function after that directly. You have to postback at success callback.

You can use simple anchor tag, asp:imagebutton not necessary.

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="btngo" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/oea_images/login_btn.png"
  OnClientClick="return clean_all();" Width="80px" />

function clean_all() {
    try {
        alert("enter");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "WebForm9.aspx/ForceOut",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msgs) {                   
                if (msgs.d == "out") {                     
                    //call btngo_Click here with __doPostback()
                    // or execute the code inside "btngo_Click"
                    // on server after "ForceOut" completed
                }
            }
        });
    } catch (ex) {
        alert(ex.Message);
    }
return false;
}
```