# Disable postback on image button click asp

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have an image button on my asp project that browse an image and display. I am using a script for my project.

This is my code:

ASPX:

```
<asp:Panel ID="stage" runat="server" cssClass="containment-wrapper" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
         <asp:ImageButton ID="imgBrowse" runat="server" Height="375px" Width="640px" src="#" />
         <input type='file' id="inpUploader" style="visibility: hidden;"/>
</asp:Panel>
```

JS [source](http://jsfiddle.net/LvsYc/):

```
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#imgBrowse').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}

$("#inpUploader").change(function () {
    readURL(this);
});
```

CS:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        imgBrowse.Attributes.Add("onclick", "document.getElementById('inpUploader').click();");
    }
```

My code is working and the image is showing after I select the image but after a few seconds the image lost because the page reloads.

Comment: Don't use Image Button. Use normal client-side `<img>` element, and assign the `src` and `click` event in client side only. No need to involve server-side postback

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem.

just add `return false;`.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        imgBrowse.Attributes.Add("onclick", "document.getElementById('inpUploader').click(); return false;");
    }
```

Comment: This worked for me. Here is another example using an image input: <input type="image" OnClick="ToggleVisibilityOff(); return false;" src="../imagesnew/home/Mobile/PlaceHolderX.jpg" />

Answer (score 1):

See this [sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703267/can-i-create-an-asp-net-imagebutton-that-doesnt-postback):

```
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Button" UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClientClick="alert('my client script here');my" />

<script type="text/javascript">

function my__doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    //Just swallow the click without postback of the form
}
</script>
```