# Prevent Image button from doing PostBack

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on `asp.net` website and I have `Imagebutton` that call `c#` function on click event. I want to prevent this image button from creating a postBack.

I have tried adding

`OnClientClick="return false;"`  and `UseSubmitBehavior="false"`

but it didn't work for me.

Do you have a solution?

I tried to call the server function through client side function as the following, but it seems there is something wrong with my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json2/20130526/json2.min.js"></script>


<script  type="text/javascript">
            $('#excelImageButton').click(function funcall() {

        $.ajax(
            {

                type: "POST",
                url: "BerthOccupancyForm.aspx/GridToExcel",
                data: "{}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",

            });

        return false;
    });

</script>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5U8D.png)

This is code behind:

```
[WebMethod()]   
public static void GridToExcel(GridView berthGridView, GridView recap)
{
    if (berthGridView.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=BerthOccupancy.xls");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        berthGridView.RenderControl(htw);

        if (RT == "Year To Date")
        {
            foreach (GridView gv in Code)
            {
                gv.RenderControl(htw);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            recap.RenderControl(htw);

        }

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(sw.ToString());
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: have you written on `page_load` for that button in server side ? Also show the full aspx of the **ImageButton**

Comment: If it is webforms you have to deal with postbacks on the serverside controls. Other way you just can't call the OnClick-Function. 

But you still always can switch to AJAX or just replace the ImageButton to simple image and call JS-Code that calls a Web-Method(which is basicaly another way to do AJAX-Like actions)

Comment: @coder i did write it in the page-load as well but it didn't work for me.

Comment: @Lorin i tried to use WebMethod. however, it requires the method to be static and i get errors in the method. Do you have an example?

Comment: @MaiShibuya yes, it should be static. And this is a bit deprecated way to do this. But it still works. 
Look into this two pages: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928533/calling-a-webmethod-with-jquery-in-asp-net-webforms 

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dacca2/static-webmethod-in-code-behind-webform/

Comment: @Lorin i tried to do the same example as you sent me, but, still the gridviewlist is still empty. can you check me code if it is possible?

Comment: @MaiShibuya could you plz edit your post and add text from .aspx and .aspx.cs or post it as a GIST on github(https://gist.github.com/) and add a link to it there so i can take a look into it.

Comment: @Lorin i've edited my post. Thanks

Comment: why are you using an ImageButton if you don't want a postback? Why not just use a standard normal image?

Comment: did you try this? ` $('#excelImageButton').click(function(e) {e.preventDefault()})`

Comment: @Ahmedilyas yeah i know that a nomal image doesn't cause a postback. But i was trying if there is s way for an imagebutton to not cause a postback by using AJAX or other method.

Comment: @PavanTeja                 $('#excelImageButton').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault()


            $.ajax(
                {
                   
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "BerthOccupancyForm.aspx/GridToExcel",
                    data: "{}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",

                });

            return false;
        });

 is it like this?

Comment: check this [fiddle](https://jsbin.com/vuvaguyaxe/edit?js,output)

Comment: @PavanTeja i want to tell you that my method has two parameters of type gridview. and i am not sure where to add them in the function since i'm very beginner in ajax and jquery

Comment: where are those gridviews?it will be very helpfill if you can share the aspx page

Comment: @PavanTeja i have added a link for the image under the ajax code in this post. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try any of the tricks given here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703267/can-i-create-an-asp-net-imagebutton-that-doesnt-postback

Comment: you can put it inside an update panel so it doesn't cause a full page postback but only a partial postback to the server. but if you are talking about using client side AJAX call to a custom method then that is a little more involved. you certainly need to set the e.preventDefault() I believe - something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710561/prevent-linkbutton-post-back-onclientclick-not-working-why

Comment: @ConnorsFan yes i did it gives Javascript error

Comment: what error did you get?

Comment: @PavanTeja thie error 0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'my' is undefined

Comment: There were many different answers in the link that I gave. If the accepted answer does not work, maybe one of the other does. One answer sets the PostBackUrl to do nothing.

Comment: ... like this: <asp:ImageButton runat="server" PostBackUrl="javascript:void(0);" .../>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys for your suggestions. I was able to solve it this way.

I have added a static class that has static List and static string. And i call this Class in the WebForm. This way keep the data of GridViews during the PostBack

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for Global
/// </summary>
public static class Global
{

    public static List<GridView> GridViewList = new List<GridView>();
    public static string ReportType = "";
}
```

The following C# Function exports to excel using the data from the static Class.

```
public  void GridToExcel()
{
    if (berthOccupancyDataGridView.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        //HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=BerthOccupancy.xls");
        //HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "";
        Response.ContentType = "text/csv";

        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        berthOccupancyDataGridView.RenderControl(htw);

        if (Global.ReportType == "Year To Date")
        {
            foreach (GridView gv in Global.GridViewList)
            {
                gv.RenderControl(htw);
            }
        }
        else if(Global.ReportType == "Monthly")
        {
            recapGridView.RenderControl(htw);

        }

        Response.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all,you cant pass `gridview` to `webmethod`.

if you seriously want to export the grid to excel use client side library to generate excel from table markup or do a partial postback and generate excel and write to response.

see this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/JaQlW4ywngTVUyHc3kXB?p=preview) to export to excel in javascript.